# How to loop sync with GET request - Async redux

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async-await, synchronization

```
const measurements: { name: string, station: string, data: any[] }[] = [];
for (const selectedTrack of selectedTracks) {
    for (const trackCircuitId of selectedTrack.tcIDs) {
        await this.props.loadMeasurements(dateFrom, dateTo, trackCircuitId, selectedTrack.station);
        console.log(this.props.measurements);
        measurements.push({
            name: trackCircuitId,
            station: selectedTrack.station,
            data: this.props.measurements
        });
    }
}

this.setState({
    measurements: measurements,
    refresh: false
});
```

await this.props.loadMeasurements(dateFrom, dateTo, trackCircuitId, selectedTrack.station);

Is calling for the action function and this.props.measurements is the prop that is returned by Redux!
I'm trying to fill the measurements list and update its state when done and render a chart.

Atm. when I load data from this.props.measurements(...), this.props.measurements is async and empty. Which makes data always to be [].

Could use componentDidUpdate, but issue lies with the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this custom loop function instead of `for`

```
const asyncForEach = async function (array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array)
  }
}

const asyncLoop = async () => {
  const measurements: { name: string, station: string, data: any[] }[] = [];
  try {
    await asyncForEach(selectedTracks, async selectedTrack => {
      await asyncForEach(selectedTrack.tcIDs, async trackCircuitId => {
        await this.props.loadMeasurements(dateFrom, dateTo, trackCircuitId, selectedTrack.station);
        console.log(this.props.measurements) // If it works well
        measurements.push({
          name: trackCircuitId,
          station: selectedTrack.station,
          data: this.props.measurements
        });
      })
    })

    this.setState({
      measurements,
      refresh: false
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

asyncLoop()
```

Comment: Could you provide an example to my code above please?

Comment: @dawood11 check my edited code above. If there is something error, please add a comment

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell that this.props.loadMeasurements is a action function that dispatches to reducer. it does not return anything. The new value is saved in this.props.measurements

Comment: If you can get the data `this.props.measurements` , just use `this.props.measurements` not return data.